# How to rename Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 account name?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I wants to rename the azure data lake storage account name of Gen1.

any one can help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to rename a storage account. You will need to create a new account, migrate date from old account to the new one and then delete the old account.

Comment: thanks for your help, can I have any reference to that

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any reference for the same.